# How can I filter out strings that contain no numbers within them?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Input:

```
apple
orang3
123rat
ratty
123
app7e
```

Output:

```
apple
ratty
```

I am trying `awk '$1 ~/[[:alpha:]]/' file` but this only removes cases like `123` that are fully numerical but I also want `app7e` and `orang3` to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To namely fit the condition *"contain no numbers"*:

Simple **`grep`** approach:

```
grep -v '[0-9]' file
```

---

Or the same with **`awk`** command:

```
awk '!/[0-9]/' file
```